# Getting Error in Xaml while Binding data with Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding

I am getting an "Invalid XAML" error while Binding data with a Converter. See this screenshot:

[image: Getting Error Here]

This is my Xaml code:

```
<DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#cbc6c0"
                                BorderThickness="3"
                                CornerRadius="3"
                                Background="#FFF9F6F4">
                            <Grid Margin="5">
                                <ContentControl Content="{Binding   Converter={StaticResource Groupdetails}}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

... and the C# code for my converter:

```
public class ListDetailsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Model_Detail ObjDetail = value as Model_Detail;

        TextBlock TbInfo = new TextBlock();
        TbInfo.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);
        TbInfo.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        TbInfo.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

        Bold TbTitle = new Bold();
        string StrTitle = ObjDetail.QuestionTitle;
        TbTitle.Inlines.Add(StrTitle);

        string StrDetails = " : " + ObjDetail.Detail;

        TbInfo.Inlines.Clear();
        TbInfo.Inlines.Add(TbTitle);
        TbInfo.Inlines.Add(StrDetails);
        return TbInfo;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

At the top of the Page xaml I have declared:

```
 xmlns:MyConverter="clr-namespace:Magnitude_Gold.MGConverter"

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <MyConverter:ListDetailsConverter x:Key="Groupdetails" />
 </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

What is wrong with this..?

Comment: I thought you should use "ListDetailsConverter" in your xaml to bind it. No?

Comment: Please edit your question so it is properly formatted. Also, don't use the tags in the title. Also, did you even bother to look at [a single code example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/10/12/xaml-binding-basics-101.aspx) to see what you're doing wrong with your Converter?

Comment: Hello , Thanks for reply I got ans on this Link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/fb20c0e2-e16b-4ff6-8ada-40791bb4e416/invalid-xaml?forum=silverlightcontrols

Answer (score 0):

Use this, Replace Model_Detail with you enity or Object

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding  Path=Model_Detail Converter={StaticResource Groupdetails}}" />
```